# I want to trigger a search upon entering a letter in entry for similar names to look up and suggest

Tags: python, database, forms, sqlite, tkinter

I'd like to trigger a search on the current field to suggest data that also begins with the entered letter to suggest that data and allow it to be entered.  I think this is called lookup and suggest.  Having a hard time describing it also makes it hard to implement.  I'm thinking that I have to:

1. Have an event to watch the field for the first typed character
2. Have that event trigger a sql query on the table where the field begins with that letter
3. Pop up a list control next to the entry field with the suggestions, if they exist
4. allow one tab from keyboard to then transfer focus to the list control
5. allow use of arrow keys to move thru list
6. when a choice is accepted, allow enter key to close list and copy the selected data to then be copied into the entry field replacing the typed letter (letters?)
7. allow the continued typing of the data while list is opened and possibly searching on the 2nd character also, and all additional characters, each refreshing the search query for similar data
8. upon entering of new data in the entry field, if no match is found, close the list control
9. close the list control at any time user types esc key
10. I think using enter key to complete user's entry of data that isn't used from lookup which closes list control
11. with no list control on form, tab control goes back to tabbing to next entry field as usual
12. initiate this during entry of new record and also during editing of a field during update of record function
13. rather than a new control, maybe I should make the entry box a combo of a drop down that has the same functionality of drawing a new control next to the entry box and since it would have a down arrow, user can also open it up even before entering the first character.

Now that I tried to describe it, I guess this may be why I don't see this functionality as often as I'd like when entering data in fields that I know already contain the same entry that I'm being asked to type again.

Does this sound like the right steps involved?

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried? It's easier to debug the code than write it from scratch.

Comment: I have to assume such questions have been asked in this site before.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are on the right track. But I would suggest you use listbox instead of a combobox as you will have more control.

> Have an event to watch the field for the first typed character

set `textvariable` to a control variable and use the trace method to notify the change.

> Have that event trigger a sql query on the table where the field begins with that letter

use `event_generate` to generate an event and bind that event to a function that will execute sql query

> Pop up a list control next to the entry field with the suggestions, if they exist

create `Listbox` and destroy it when there is no suggestions.

> close the list control at any time user types esc key

simply bind `<Escape>` to a function and destroy the list box

> allow the continued typing of the data while list is opened and possibly searching on the 2nd character also, and all additional characters, each refreshing the search query for similar data

can be achieved using `Like` in sql

example code:

Entry.py

```py
import tkinter as tk

class CustomEntryBox(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, text='', callback=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.listbox = None
        self.scrollbar = None

        self.lstValues = ()

        self.callback = callback

        if self.callback:
            self.callback = self.register(callback)
        
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.traceId = self.var.trace('w', self._textChanged)
        
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self, borderwidth=0, background="white",relief="groove", textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='left')
        
        self.enterButton = tk.Button(self, text=text, background="white", command=self._btnClicked)  # reove this if not necessary
        self.enterButton.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        self.entry.bind('<Escape>', self._removeListView)   
        self.entry.bind("<Down>", self._changeSelection)
        self.entry.bind("<Up>", self._changeSelection)
        self.entry.bind('<Return>', self._btnClicked)
        
        #self.previousIndex = 0
        self.selection = -1

        self.bind('<Configure>', self._updatePos)

    def _textChanged(self, *args):  # generates text changed event when there is a change in text
        self.event_generate('<<TextChanged>>', when='head', data=self.var.get())

        if self.callback:
            self.tk.call("bind", self, '<<TextChanged>>', self.callback + " %d")
        
    def _btnClicked(self, event=None): # generates Buttonclicked event when the button is clicked
        self._removeListView()
        self.event_generate('<<ButtonClicked>>', when='tail')
    
    def _changeSelection(self, event):  # uses mouse to move up and down the list

         if self.listbox:

            if event.keysym == "Down" and self.selection < self.listbox.size() -1:
                self.listbox.select_clear(self.selection)
                self.selection += 1
                self.listbox.select_set(self.selection)
                

            elif event.keysym == "Up" and self.selection > -1:

                self.listbox.select_clear(self.selection)
                self.selection -= 1
                if self.selection != -1:
                    self.listbox.select_set(self.selection)

            self.listbox.see(self.selection)
            self.setEntry()
    
    def _listView(self, event=None):  # creates listbox in a frame

        if self.listbox is None:
            
            self.frame = tk.Frame(background=self['bg'] ,width=self.entry['width']+2)
            self.frame.lift()
            self.frame.place(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height()-2, width=self.winfo_width())
            
            self.listbox = tk.Listbox(self.frame, width=self.entry['width'], border=1, relief="groove", activestyle='none')
            self.listbox.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='both')
            
            self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.setEntry)
            self.listbox.bind("<Motion>", self._highlight)
            self.listbox.bind("<Leave>", self._removeHighlight)

        
    def _updatePos(self, event):  # updates the position of the listbox according to the postion of the entry
        if self.listbox:
            self.frame.place_configure(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y()+self.winfo_height()-2, width=self.winfo_width())

    def _updateListHeight(self):  # adds scrollbar when necessary `if self.listbox.size()>5:` <- change this constant to allow the list view to grow

        if self.listbox:
            
             if self.listbox.size()>5:
                self.listbox.configure(height=5)

                if self.scrollbar is None:
                    self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.frame, command = self.listbox.yview)
                    self.scrollbar.pack(side='right',  fill="y")
                    self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set)
           
             else:
                 self.listbox.configure(height=len(list(self.lstValues)))

                 if self.scrollbar:
                    self.scrollbar.destroy()
                    self.scrollbar = None


    def _removeListView(self, event=None):  # removes the listbox when not necessary
        if self.listbox:
             self.frame.destroy()
             self.listbox = None
             self.scrollbar = None
        
    def _highlight(self, event):  # highlights the cell which is under the mouse

        # uncomment the below three lines and comment the uncommented lines if you don't want the selection changed but only the background
        
        #self.listbox.itemconfig(self.previousIndex, background='white')
        #self.previousIndex = self.listbox.nearest(event.y)
        #self.listbox.itemconfig(self.previousIndex, background='lightblue')

        self.listbox.select_clear(self.selection)
        self.selection = self.listbox.nearest(event.y)
        self.listbox.select_set(self.selection)

    def _removeHighlight(self, event):  # removes the highlight when outside the listbox
        self.listbox.select_clear(self.selection)
        #self.listbox.itemconfig(self.previousIndex, background='white')

    def updateValues(self):  # updates the list box values
        
        if self.listbox:

            if len(self.var.get())==0 or len(self.lstValues)==0:
                 self._removeListView()
                 return
            
            self.selection = -1
            self.listbox.delete(0, tk.END)
            
            for index, element in enumerate(self.lstValues):
                self.listbox.insert(index, element)

            self._updateListHeight()


    def setEntry(self, event=None):  # this function is responsible for changing the text in the entry

        if self.listbox.curselection():
            
            self.var.trace_vdelete('w', self.traceId)
            
            selection = self.listbox.curselection()[0]
            self.listbox.select_set(selection)

            self.entry.delete(0, 'end')
            self.entry.insert(0, self.listbox.get(selection)[0])

            self.traceId = self.var.trace('w', self._textChanged)

            if event:
                self._removeListView()
                
            
    def updateSearchLst(self, values:list):  # this is the only method that you are allowed to access pass a list
        self.lstValues = values
        if len(self.lstValues) > 0 and self.listbox is None:
            self._listView()
        
        self.updateValues()

    def getCurrent(self):  # returns the entry use 
        return self.var.get()
```

file.py

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

from Entry import CustomEntryBox

def fun(args):
    if len(args) >= 0:
        lst = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM dictionary WHERE word LIKE ?;", (args+'%',))
        record = lst.fetchall()
        ent.updateSearchLst(record)

def search(event):
    print("search clicked")

def wordsToDB():
 
    for word in ['hello', 'helloo','hellooo','helloooo','hellooooo','helo', 'world', 'very', 'Big']:

        try:
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO dictionary VALUES(?);", (word,))
        except Exception:
            pass
        
    conn.commit()        
    
root = tk.Tk()

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

try:
    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE DICTIONARY (WORD CHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);")

except Exception:
    pass

wordsToDB()

ent = CustomEntryBox(root, text='search', callback=fun)  
ent.bind("<<ButtonClicked>>", search)
# ent.bind("<<TextChanged>>", lambda event:print("text: ", ent.getCurrent())) # do not pass the callback argument in to the constructor if you want to use this
ent.pack()

root.mainloop()
```